# Can I resume an interruped single file upload to Google Drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm uploading a single file of 8gb's to my Google Drive installed in my Windows. If I turn off my computer, it will resume from its last progress?? I'm asking this because I don't see any progress bar...

Answer (score 3):

From experience, *Google Drive cannot resume a partial file upload*.

**Context**: My 760MB upload has not completed over the period of a day (should take about 2 hours). It can only upload a whole file at a time, and if that gets interrupted due to Internet failure, it restarts the file from the beginning. Our Internet fails about every 1-2 hours, which is why my 760MB upload will literally continue 'forever'.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems that Google Drive will re-start any interrupted uploads from the beginning -- if you turn off your computer, it will restart the upload from the beginning when you turn it back on and try the upload again.

If you can't keep your computer or internet on long enough for a file to upload, you can use a Zip or other archiving utility like 7-Zip to split the large file into multiple smaller pieces and upload those pieces one by one.

This way the "cost" of a failed transfer is only as large as each individual piece. I tried to comment this to the other answer posted here regarding the 2-hour internet disconnect time, but don't have enough rep points to do so.

To split a file:

1. Install 7Zip from https://www.7-zip.org/download.html
   If you're on Windows, you probably want the second link on the page, i.e., 7-Zip for 64-bit Windows
2. Install it, and enable context menu shortcuts.
3. Then, right click on the file you want to split, hover over the "7-Zip" context menu, then click "Add to archive".

On the window that pops up, select Zip as archive format (for maximum compatibility, or use the 7z format if you will be the only one downloading this file), choose "Store" for compression level (for speed; choose a higher level if you want to compress the file), and then at the bottom left where it says "Split to volume, bytes", enter "50M" (for 50 megabytes) or another value -- this is the file size of each split file "chunk".

[7Zip Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMe8M.png)

Note that this isn't really a solution as much as a workaround - however if you have no way to upload a large file due to internet disconnects or another related problem, then it may be an acceptable solution for you.